# What is cosubordination?

Tags: terminology

I've been searching the internet for an answer to this question, but found only a reference to "cosubordination" being neither coordination nor subordination strictly speaking.

Does "cosubordination" have any relation to clause-chaining?

Comment: It could mean a lot of different things. Terminology gets introduced and forgotten pretty frequently in grammar. If you can't find any reference for it, why worry about it? It's clearly not being used coherently, so it's not a concept one needs to understand.

Comment: Well, I've heard of subordination and I've heard of clause-chaining, and I wanted to see if natural languages had any alternatives to these two.

Comment: Ah, RRG. Then it's related to serial verbs and constructions like _come sit down, go get me a beer, blow dry your hair,_ and the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cosubordination is similar to both coordinate structure and subordinate structure simultaneously.

> http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/uhlcs/LENCA/LENCA-3/information/abstract-files/van-valin-robert-2.pdf

This is most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: The Van Valin example uses Chechen. I don't think he needed to go so exotic. The Japanese -て (-te) form is used in the same way. "Kinō uchi e kaette kite, gohan o tabete, shinbun o yonde, terebi wo mite, shawā o abite nemashita." "Yesterday (I) came home, ate dinner, read the newspaper, watched TV, had a shower and went to bed". I think it is found in many so-called Altaic languages and possibly elsewhere, too.